# Basic java synchronization

Tags: java, synchronization

i have a question, what is difference between

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
public void sync(){
  synchronized(sb){
  };
}
```

and

```
public void sync(){
  synchronized(this){
  };
}
```

Comment: Why such a big meaning less title?

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to use a StringBuilder or StringBuffer in a multi-threaded context.  You should be bale to write your code without synchronizing on this class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, you lock on "sb" variable, and in the second case, in "this" object.
This is obvious, but i suppose you want to know **which is better**.

Well, the first case is better, because you lock on a local variable (consider to make it private) and you are quite sure that no other is going to lock on it than you.
If you lock on "this", any other thread could use this object to lock, preventing you from running the synchronized code (whereas you safely could).

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same syntax. In both cases, you're synchronizing using a particular reference - the synchronized block will acquire the monitor associated with the object that the reference refers to. In both cases, other threads will be blocked if they try to acquire the monitor for the same object, until the original thread releases the monitor.

It's just that in the first case the reference is `sb`, and in the second case it's `this`. The value of `this` is just a reference, like any other (except guaranteed not to be null).

Answer (score 0):

In java synchronization is done around a concept called a [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29). The argument to the `synchronized` is which monitor you are locking.